# How to search from table using any charcter in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue. I am searching the data from table by giving the letter as input using PHP and MySQL.Here i am facing some issue while searching. I am explaining my code below.

```
$searchKey=$_GET['searchKey'];
$keyword = $searchKey.'%';
$sql =mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM  db_restaurant_basic WHERE rest_name LIKE '".$keyword."' and special='".$special_id."' and city='".$city_id."' and status=1 ORDER BY member_id DESC ");
```

Here if can putting the direct name then search functionality can work. Suppose I have one rest_name `The Joyce` and I want to search this. When user is putting the name directly like `The Joyce or The` then its working but if user is searching like this `Joyce` only its not working but it should work. Similarly there is a another rest_name `Toad 'n' Turtle`. If user will put `Toad or 'n' or Turtle` it should work which is not working in my current case. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use it as `$keyword = '%'.$searchKey.'%';`

Comment: Try `$keyword = LOWER('%'.$searchKey.'%');`

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) attacks. You should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyword = $searchKey.'%';
```

In this case it will search only the word starting with "$keyword"

```
$keyword = '%'.$searchKey;
```

In this case it will search only the word ending with "$keyword"

If you want to select all the words which contains "$keyword"
you have to change your searchKey to

```
$keyword = '%'.$searchKey.'%';
```